# Python copy and rename many small csv files based on selected characters within the files

Tags: python, csv

I'm not a programmer; I'm a pilot who has done just a little bit of scripting in a past life, so I'm completely non-current at this.  I have searched the forum and found somewhat similar problems that, with more expertise and time I might be able to adapt to my problem, but I hope I can get closer by asking my own question.  I hope my problem is unique enough that those considering answering do not feel their time is wasted, considering my disadvantage.  Anyway here is my problem:

Some of my crew members periodically have a need to rename a few hundred to more than 1,000 small csv files based on a specific convention applied to their contents.  Not all of the files are used in a given project, but any subset of them could be used, so automation makes a lot of sense here.  Currently this is done manually as needed.  I can easily move all these files into a single directory for processing, since all their file names are unique as received.

Here are representative excerpts from two example csv files, preceded by their respective file names (As I receive them):

---

A_13LSAT_2014-04-23_1431.csv:

```
1,KDAL CURLO RW13L SAT 20140414_0644,SID,N/A,DDI
2,*,RW13L(AER),SAT
3,RW13L(AER),+325123.36,-0965121.20,RW31R(DER),+325031.35,-0965020.95
4,1,1.2,+325123.36,-0965121.20,0.0,+325031.35,-0965020.95,2.0
3,RW31R(DER),+325031.35,-0965020.95,GH13L,+324947.23,-0964929.84
4,1,2.4,+325031.35,-0965020.95,0.0,+324947.23,-0964929.84,2.0
5,TTT,0,0
5,CVE,0,0
```

---

A_RROSEE_2014-04-03_1419.csv:

```
1,KDFW SEEVR STAR RRONY SEEVR 20140403_1340,STAR,N/A,DDI
2,*,RRONY,SEEVR
3,RRONY,+333455.16,-0952530.56,ROWZE,+333233.02,-0954016.52
4,1,12.6,+333455.16,-0952530.56,0.0,+333233.02,-0954016.52,2.0
5,EIC,0,1
5,SLR,0,0
```

---

I know these files are not code, but I entered them indented in this post so they would display properly.

The files must be renamed due to the 8.3 limitation of the platform they are used on.
The convention is:

•On the first line, the first two characters in the second word of the second "cell" (Which are the 6th and 7th characters of the second cell), and,

•on line 2, the first three characters of the third cell, and

•the first three characters of the fourth cell.

The contents and format of the files must remain unaltered.  In theory this convention yields unique names for every file so duplication of file names should not be a problem.

The files above would be copied and renamed respectively to:

CURW1SAT.csv

SERROSEE.csv

That's it.  Just a script that will scan a directory full of these csv files, and create renamed copies in the same directory according the the convention I just described, based on their contents.  I'm attempting to use Activestate Python 2.7.7.

Thanks in advance for any consideration.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

It's not what you'd call pretty, but neither am I; and it works (and it's simple)

```
import os
import glob

fileset = set(glob.glob(os.path.basename(os.path.join(".", "*.csv"))))
for filename in fileset:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        csv_file = f.readlines()
    out = csv_file[0].split(",")[1].split(" ")[1][:2]
    out += csv_file[1].split(",")[2][:3]
    out += csv_file[1].split(",")[3][:3]
    os.rename(filename, out + ".csv")
```

just drop this in the folder with all the csv's to be renamed and run it

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed not too complicated. Python has out of the box everything you need.
I don't think it's a good idea to rename the files, in case of error (e.g. collision) it would make the process dangerous, copying to another folder is safer.
The code could look like that:

```
import csv
import os
import os.path
import sys
import shutil

def Process(input_directory, output_directory, filename):
  """This methods reads the file named 'filename' in input_directory and copies
     it to output_directory, renaming it."""

  # Read the file and extract first 2 lines.
  with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line1 = reader.next()
    line2 = reader.next()

  line1_second_cell = line1[1]
  # split() separate words by spaces into a list, [1] takes the second.
  second_word = line1_second_cell.split()[1]

  line2_third_cell = line2[2]
  line2_fourth_cell = line2[3]

  # [:2] takes the first two characters from a string.
  new_filename = second_word[:2] + line2_third_cell[:3] + line2_fourth_cell[:3]
  new_filename += '.csv'

  print 'copying', filename, 'to', new_filename

  shutil.copyfile(
      os.path.join(input_directory, filename),
      os.path.join(output_directory, new_filename))


# sys.argv is the list of arguments passed on the command line.
if len(sys.argv) == 3:
  input_directory = sys.argv[1]
  output_directory = sys.argv[2]

  # os.listdir gives all the files in the directory (including ., .. and sub
  # directories).
  for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
      Process(input_directory, output_directory, filename)
else:
  print "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "source_directory target_directory"
```

On windows you can run it in a command line (cmd.exe):

```
C:\where_your_python_is\python.exe C:\where_your_script_is\renamer.py C:\input C:\output
```

On linux it would be a little simpler as the python binary is in the path:

```
python /where_your_script_is/renamer.py /input /output
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a script, and when you run it, give it the directory name as an argument on the command line:

```
import csv
import sys
import os  

def rename_csv_file(filename):
    global directory
    with open(filename,'r') as csv_file:
        newfilename = str()
        rownum = 0
        filereader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
        for row in filereader:
            if rownum == 0:
                newfilename = row[1].split()[1][:2]
            elif rownum == 1:
                newfilename += row[2][:3]
                newfilename += row[3][:3]
                break
            rownum += 1
    newfilename += '.csv'
    newfullpath = os.path.join(directory,newfilename)
    os.rename(filename,newfullpath)


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Usage: {} directory_name".format(sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit()

directory = sys.argv[1]
csvfiles = [ os.path.join(directory,f) for f in os.listdir(directory) if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory,f)) and f.endswith('.csv')) ]

for f in csvfiles:
    rename_csv_file(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that every csv in your directory needs to be renamed.  The code could be  more condensed, but I tried to spell it out a bit so you could see what was going on.

```
import os
import csv
import shutil

#change this to the directory where your csvs are stored
dirname = r'C:\yourdirectory' 

os.chdir(dirname)

for item in os.listdir(dirname): #look through directory contents
    if item.endswith('.csv'):
        f = open(item)
        r = csv.reader(f)
        line1 = r.next() #get the first line of csv
        line2 = r.next() #get the second line of csv
        f.close()

    name1 = line1[1][:2] #first part of your name
    name2 = line2[2][:3] #second part
    name3 = line2[3][:3] #third part

    newname = name1+name2+name3+'.csv'

    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(dirname,item),newname) #copied csv with newname
```